# I have a problem with the function $readmemh

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a problem in the function `$readmemh`.

It works just when I write the full path for the file, but when I write the name of the file, it doesn't work.
How to solve this problem without writing the full path, so I can transfer the code between more than one device without changing the code each time?

First try:

```
 initial
 begin
     $readmemh("dataMemory_init.mem", dataMemory); // Read data from hex file and initialize mem
 end
```

Second try:

```
 initial
 begin
     $readmemh("dataMemory_init.txt", dataMemory); // Read data from hex file and initialize mem
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify a full path to the file, the simulator expects the file to already exist in the current working directory (the directory where you run the simulator command).

If you run your simulation as part of a script (which is a common practice), you can either copy file `dataMemory_init.mem` into the directory where you run the simulation or by linking to the file.  This would be done prior to running the simulation command.

Refer also to this question: [Call $readmemh() on global path of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358072/call-readmemh-on-global-path-of-file)

Answer (score 0):

Use a symlink.
Create a simlink in the directory where the simulation is running that points to the file.
If this is a script based build flow, use the script to create the link based on context which the known to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use verilog $value$plusarg() to get directory name from simulation command line argument. For example, declare a new plus argument "+dir" for passing directory name to simulator. Here is the sample code:

```
`define MEM_FILE "test.mem"
module tb;
reg [7:0] mem[7:0];  // Memory array
string dir;  // Directory name string
string fname;  // Full file name string
initial
begin
    if ( $value$plusargs( "dir=%s", dir ) )
    begin
        $display( "dir = %s", dir );
        fname = { dir, "/", `MEM_FILE };
    end
    else
        fname = `MEM_FILE;
    $display( "fname = %s", fname );
    $readmemh( fname, mem );
    $display( "mem[0] = %h", mem[0] );
    $display( "mem[1] = %h", mem[1] );
    $finish;
end
endmodule
```

If you want to change the directory name, run simulator (e.g. vcs) with argument:

```
vcs +dir=/path/to tb.v
```